# How to randomly update rows in SQL for entire table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where for a column id, I want to randomly assign it "a","b", or "c" randomly and equally. There's also a condition where name has to be "test".

```
UPDATE table
WHERE name="test"
SET id=
CASE WHEN rand() < 1/3 THEN "a"
CASE WHEN rand() < 2/3 THEN "b"
CASE WHEN rand() < 1 THEN "c"
```

I'm not sure how this would work though, because I'm not sure if rand() will run for every row?
I'm pretty new to SQL so this is a bit confusing, thanks!

Comment: "_I'm not sure how this would work though, because I'm not sure if rand() will run for every row?_" It will run for every row, but it might also run for every `case when` in your overcomplicated example. The easy way to be sure whether it'll return different random numbers is to try it and see...

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question

Just use arithmetic:

```
UPDATE table
    SET id = 1 + floor(rand * 3)
    WHERE name = 'test'
```

Comment: Oh I guess I should have been more specific, the id's won't be numbers, they'll be names in string form, my bad. I made an edit

Comment: @chung so just do `case floor(rand * 3) when 0 then 'A' when 1 then 'B' when 2 then 'C'`.

Comment: Just using rand() will not guarantee equal distribution of the three cases (especially if the number of rows is not large). See my answer below.

Comment: @chung . . . Your question was quite clear and the values were numbers.  I don't know why you changed the question to invalidate this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If by *randomly and equally* you mean that you want to ensure the number of rows in the 3 groups are distributed as equally as possible, you have to use `ntile()` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(   pk serial primary key,
    id varchar,
    name character varying 
)


insert into test (name)values(generate_series(1,150)::varchar);

--99 rows of test data:
update test set name = 'test' where pk < 100;

-- partition by random and divide into 3 equal parts:
SELECT t.*, ntile(3) over(order by random())AS n from test t where name = 'test'  ;

-- use this select in an update query:
UPDATE test 
SET id = case sel.n when 1 then 'a'  
                    when 2 then 'b' 
                    when 3 then 'c' 
                    END  
FROM
(SELECT t.*, ntile(3) over(order by random())AS n 
FROM test t WHERE name = 'test'  
)sel
WHERE sel.pk = test.pk;

-- test result
select count(*) from test where name = 'test' group by id;
-- 33
-- 33
-- 33
```